# How to sort more then 100 sheets in spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have google spreadsheet whit more then 100 sheets and i need to sort it by alphabet. Now i have script

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetArray = ss.getSheets();
  var sheetNameArray = [];

  for(var i = 0; i<sheetArray.length; i++){ 
    sheetNameArray.push(sheetArray[i].getSheetName());
  };
 
  sheetNameArray.sort();
  sheetNameArray.forEach(function (element) {
         var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(element);
         ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);
         ss.moveActiveSheet(ss.getNumSheets())
    })
```

This run in `onEdit`. But it's work more then 30 seconds and cannot complete. What should i do?

Comment: why do you need an onEdit trigger for that? Also I am not sure if your code sorts alphabetically anyways.

Comment: @Marios for me it is not very important what event this happens but onEdit it's best for me. Also why do you think it's not sorting? I try to log input and output arrays and i get result i need

Comment: sorry, you code indeed sorts correctly. However, I improved it a little bit. Try it out and let me know if it works within 30 seconds.

Comment: You can try using the Advanced Sheets service. Its better-suited for optimizing bulk operations when compared to the built-in service, so it might be possible to build a solution that runs under 30 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

I think this would work faster because I tested both codes:

```
function sortSheets() {   
   const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   const allSheets = ss.getSheets();
   const sheetsAr = allSheets.map(sh=>[sh,sh.getName()]);
   sheetsAr.sort((a,b) => a[1].charCodeAt(0)-b[1].charCodeAt(0));
   sheetsAr.forEach((v,i)=>{
                   ss.setActiveSheet(v[0]);
                   ss.moveActiveSheet(i+1);                   
   });
}
```

You will gain some performance because I got rid of the `for` loop.

If this does not work, I am afraid you have to use a time-driven trigger which can run from 6 minutes (if you have a consumer account) or 30 minutes (if you have a business account). You can set up the time driven trigger to run every 1 minute or longer so you can have a sort of "live" adjustments in the orders of the sheet.

Comment: It's work better! Thanks! But still too long to work every time. I decided that I would solve it in a different way. I will change the positions of one sheet as I edit it. This should help